# How can I get notifications from two Android phones to one Android Wear watch?

Tags: notifications, nexus-5, samsung-galaxy-s-5, android-wear

I have a Nexus 5 as my personal phone, a Samsung Galaxy S5 as my work phone, and an LG Urbane watch.

Currently my watch is linked to the Nexus 5 and due to Android Wear limitations it seems I can't connect a second phone to it. Surprisingly it doesn't look like I can find any workaround anywhere online to force the watch to allow multiple connections, however I'm sure there is some way I can at least get limited functionality.

So my question is does anyone know how I could get this to work? The two phones are ALWAYS together so I was hoping for something even as bare minimum as call and text notifications on the Samsung being forwarded over bluetooth to the Nexus that will then send it to the watch.

My Nexus has all the fun Android Wear stuff on it, I just need call/text/email notifications from the Samsung, I don't even need to be able to interact with them, just need to see it. Also rooting may be possible if required, for any device watch included. And I'm okay with paid apps (free is better) but monthly charges are a no-go ever.

Comment: You can't - https://support.google.com/androidwear/answer/6058799?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of applications in the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=tablet%20phone%20callerid%20notifications&c=apps) which are designed to allow a tablet to send/receive SMS/MMS via a connected phone. If you connect your watch-connected phone as the "tablet", you should at least be able to get notifications for some subset of events to show on your watch.

Caveat - I have used [Tablet Talk](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apdroid.tabtalk) for this purpose on a non-android wear watch, but not recently, and I don't recall all the limitations.